# Admob failed to load with error "at nativeToJSError" - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, admob

**Issue**

I have apps currently running in the product version of my app but for some reason without making any changes to my code I now get the following error when testing my React Native on Android.  I've tried both in the android emulator on my computer and on an android device connected to my computer.

It's working perfectly for iOS and worked perfectly for Android before today.

I enabled my ads weeks ago so its not an issue of a lack of inventory, which would show in my debugger as a lack of inventory if that was the case

If anyone has suggestions that would be great! This is preventing me from pushing an important update for my users.

**Error**

```
result     at nativeToJSError (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:105783:17)
    at AdMobComponent._this.onBannerEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:106684:64)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:7899:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:7990:37)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:7994:31)
    at executeDispatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:8188:9)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:8208:11)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:8303:11)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:8312:16)
    at forEachAccumulated (blob:http://localhost:8081/6fcdf141-5854-4a90-ba10-5e5c347584ab:8295:14)
```

**Arguments passed back by error**

```
Arguments [callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
 callee: ƒ render()
  arguments: null
  caller: null
  length: 0
  name: "render"
  prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
  __proto__: ƒ ()
  [[FunctionLocation]]: Admob.js:33
  [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
  length: 0
 Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
  arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and  'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
  caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
  length: 0
  name: "values"
  __proto__: ƒ ()
  [[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
  __proto__: Object
```

**Admob Component Code**
The code is exactly as it is from the react-native app, the only change I've made is removing the app & unit Ids.  I've checked to ensure they are correct through.

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Dimensions,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';


const Analytics = firebase.analytics()
const Admob = firebase.admob()
const Banner = firebase.admob.Banner;
const AdRequest = firebase.admob.AdRequest;
const request = new AdRequest().addTestDevice()


export default class AdmobComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    Admob.initialize('Removed for privacy')
    this.state = {};

  }
  onBannerPress() {
    console.log('add button butotn pushed')
    Analytics.logEvent('banner_click')

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          style={styles.adMobTouch}
          onPress={() => this.onBannerPress()}

        >
          <Banner
            size={"SMART_BANNER"}
            unitId={'Removed for private'}
            request={request.build()}
            onAdLoaded={() => {
              console.log('Advert loaded');
            }}
            onAdFailedToLoad={(result) => {
              console.log('result', result)
              console.log('Ad failed to load', arguments)
            }}
          />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: same here buddy... same scenario

Answer (score 4):

For development purposes `unitId` need to be one of the predefined values https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=en-GB

1. **Banner:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`
2. **Interstitial:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`
3. **Interstitial Video:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433`
4. **Rewarded Video:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917`
5. **Native Advanced:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110`
6. **Native Advanced Video:**

   - `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error, it is actually not an error, you just have to make a production release apk, when there will be so many hits to admob from your users then admob will start showing real ads, meanwhile you will still see this error on the development mode but will work fine in the production mode of your apk, just make the release apk and the ads will start with in 24 Hours when there are too many request for ads from your app!..

More information ===> https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2054